# Would a terraformed Martian athmosphere even persist?

Tags: mars, terraforming

So I saw a question here mentioning that omnipresent idea of terraforming  mars by somehow giving it more atmosphere (here it was melting/evaporating the polar ice caps).

My problem with that is: wouldn't that atmosphere be blown away by solar winds etc.?

I mean there's probably is a reason why it has such a weak one to begin with (or so I thought).

Does nobody (including Elon Musk, who proposed melting the evaporating the caps with nuclearfusion bombs) consider this or would the rate of this loss be low enough for it to be viable?

Comment: Here is a list of some related questions. It is an incomplete list, but there's a good chance there is a duplicate here somewhere. Duplicate means that the question has an answer that also answers your question. https://space.stackexchange.com/a/27539/12102

Comment: It's all about timescales. I don't know the numbers, but if the atmosphere was lost over a million years it would be quick on astronomical timescales but quite long enough for a colony

Comment: Just going to say that "long enough for a colony" is a dirty trick to play on the descendants of said colony.

Comment: If it's a million years, you can assume that your descendants are going to have tools not at your disposal, to say the least.