# Would a system of geosynchronous magnetic field satelites around Mars protect it from solar wind?

Tags: mars, engineering, terraforming, satellite-constellation, solar-wind

My entire life I've been obsessed with space travel, for the passed few years I've liked the idea of terraforming. I've learned a lot lately and i think I'm ready to begin research for some simulations. My question is, would a system of geosynchronous satellites, all generating an incredibly strong magnetic field, be able to stop atmosphere stripping on Mars? Asking because I'm only a teenager and may be missing something, and if this is possible, does anyone know how powerful the satellites would have to be? And how would it be powered?

Comment: I have a long list of questions about Mars terraforming and magnetic fields in [this answer to *Is Mars' gravity strong enough to hold a human-breathable atmosphere?*](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/27539/12102) Basically the timescale for atmosphere loss due to the solar wind is really really long, maybe you would have to add a new atmosphere every million or hundred million years. So the magnetic field is not necessary.

Comment: There are several Q & A about this in Astronomy SE: [...but where did Mars' atmosphere actually GO?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/45205/7982) (lively discussion in comments) and [Why is Mars' atmosphere so thin?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/2310/7982) and [Loss of atmosphere on Mars](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/712/7982) and now go back and see the long string of comments under [...but where did Mars' atmosphere actually GO?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/45204/7982) which calls the whole solar wind idea into question!

Comment: The problem with an orbiting satellite that generates a *strong* magnetic field, it that it *very soon* becomes a non-orbiting satellite. The magnetic field would apply sustained thrust to the device. That's ignoring the several-orders-of-magnitude difference between available power sources (solar, even nuclear) and a device capable of outputting a planetary-scale magnetic field of sufficient strength.

Comment: A recent publication from (among others) *the* Jim Green might be of interest: ["How to create an artificial magnetosphere for Mars"](https://arxiv.org/abs/2111.06887)

Comment: A geosynchronous orbit (sometimes abbreviated GSO) is an Earth-centered orbit with an orbital period that matches Earth's rotation on its axis, 23 hours, 56 minutes, and 4 seconds (one sidereal day). Are you asking for satellites in orbit around Mars or Earth? May be you should delete the word geosynchronous in the headline.

Comment: Don't you think that would be better suited to SE Worldbuilding?